# VNC into Raspberry Pi 3B+ using ethernet cable on Mac OSX loses connection when wifi on Mac is turned on

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ connected to a Macbook Air via an ethernet cable into a ethernet-USB adapter on the Macbook.  I am able to connect to the Pi when my Macbook's wifi is disconnected.  However, as soon as I turn on wifi, I lose signal over the ethernet connection to the Pi, and I can no longer see VNC or ssh.

I have tried:

- reordering the serve preferences in the network settings
- disabling / enabling internet sharing

Any thoughts would be appreciated! Many thanks